# Python: lambda vs if/else

Tags: python, lambda

I tried to replace `lambda self.status: partial if max_refundable == amount else self.status = refunded` with if/else to make it in one line. However, it doesn't work as expected. Anyone knows where the problem is?

```
if max_refundable == amount:
    self.status = partial
else:
    self.status = refunded
```

Comment: Can you expand this to a [mcve] showing what happened with the old code and what's not happening with the new code?

Comment: Your lambda is not valid python(3) code

Comment: Do you mean you tried to replace your if-else with a lambda, or do you mean you tried to replace your lambda with an if-else, because your if-else should work, but your lambda should not.

Comment: Thank you for all the comments @FHTMitchell solved it for me. I misunderstood the use of lambda.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because that is invalid syntax

```
lambda self.status: partial if max_refundable == amount else self.status = refunded
```

is equivelent to

```
def _lambda_func_(self.status):
    return partial if max_refundable == amount else self.status = refunded
```

which isn't what you want (`self.status` is not a valid argument name). You don't need a function, just do

```
self.status = partial if max_refundable == amount else refunded
```

Comment: Now it makes sense, sorry I completely misunderstood the use of lamda. That was very helpful, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The syntax is as follows:

```
a = 1
b = 3
a = a+b if a == 2 else b
```

In your case, it would look like this:

```
self.status = partial if max_refundable == amount else refunded
```